# Any suggestion for a Java web MVC framework that does not affect server startup

Tags: java, model-view-controller, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'd like to know if there are any suggestions for a Java web development framework that does not add startup overhead. The reason for asking is that I'm planning to deploy on Google App Engine and I do not want to increase the cold start time for the server. So any framework with minimum configuration overhead, or possibly deferred configuration until first call to the framework would be interesting. The framework is to be used for backend administration pages so those pages do not affect customers, but increasing the server startup time certainly does.

Thanks
Klas

Comment: Have you looked into startup times on GAE ?

Comment: I have not myself made any measurements of web frameworks yet. I have read that for example SpringMVC can add 6 seconds of startup time. Also Struts and others seem to add significant overhead, so before going through all and measuring, I asked this question if anyone already knows of a framework that adds miminal overhead

Comment: GAE startup time is significant, I can believe 6 seconds if there is a framework to initialise, though you can now pay for an always on JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vanilla Servlet / JSP framework should do the job. POJOs as Model objects. Servlets as Controllers. JSPs for Views. The JSPs are pre-compiled, servlets will only be instantiated on demand (assuming load-on-startup is false) and of course POJOs are POJOs.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I have right now, and maybe you are right, and this is the only option today. Hopefully someone else can hint on an existing framework, otherwise your answer is the right one currently

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) which can run off of the [Google App Engine](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.3/deployment#aGoogleApplicationEngineGAEa).

I was [looking for a better Java platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190335/languages-stacks-for-deployment) and have been using Play! for the past few weeks. Definitely something I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I will look into Play!. So have you deployed it on Google App Engine, and if so , do you have any measurement on how long time it takes to start?
Thanks
Klas

Comment: @Klas: We aren't using the GAE, so I'm not sure. I would recommend downloading the YABE app for Play! and running through the deployment process to get a feel for it though.

Comment: Ok, thanks Josh, I will test it out, and get back on how it affects the startup time